# Where does docker bridge send network packets?

Tags: docker

Please explain something. docker0 bridge has gateway IP 172.17.0.1. So all containers send their network traffic to this IP. I can't understand how the bridge knows where to send this traffic after? Does the docker bridge have its own iptables within with a configured gateway?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions relating to software development. For general computer usage question like this, consider https://superuser.com, or maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com.